# Multi-join 'gotohell' update

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, inner-join

I've got this select query that returns simple table - see below.

I spent the whole day trying to write an update statement that when EQLOC is NULL or not the same as HOOKNO then it should be updated with HOOKNO... but I failed miserably.

Please help.

```
SELECT ho.HOOK_OFFICE_LETTER || LPAD(khc.HOOK_NO, 5, '0') as hookno, eq.location_description as eqloc
FROM KEY_HOOK_CURRENT khc 
    INNER JOIN KEY_HOLDING kho                ON khc.KEY_HOLDINGOID = kho.KEY_HOLDINGOID
    INNER JOIN CONTRACT con                   ON kho.CUSTOMEROID = con.CUSTOMEROID
    INNER JOIN VW_CURRENT_CONTRACT_PERIOD ccp ON con.CONTRACT_ID = ccp.CONTRACT_ID
    INNER JOIN CONTRACT_PERIOD cp             ON (ccp.CONTRACT_ID = cp.CONTRACT_ID AND ccp.CONTRACT_PERIOD = cp.CONTRACT_PERIOD)
    INNER JOIN CONTRACT_EQUIP_PERIOD cep      ON cp.CONTRACT_PERIODOID = cep.CONTRACT_PERIODOID
    INNER JOIN EQUIPMENT eq                   ON cep.EQUIPMENTOID = eq.EQUIPMENTOID
    INNER JOIN HOOK_OFFICE ho                 ON khc.HOOK_OFFICEOID = ho.HOOK_OFFICEOID
WHERE
    eq.PRODUCT_ID = 'XXX' AND
    (eq.LOCATION_DESCRIPTION IS NULL OR
    ho.HOOK_OFFICE_LETTER || LPAD(khc.HOOK_NO, 5, '0') <> eq.LOCATION_DESCRIPTION)
```

Query returns following:

```
HOOKNO  EQLOC
G00754  (null)
L02860  (null)
L04052  L12345
L01126  (null)
L01348  (null)
L01950  L56789
L00857  (null)
L04651  (null)
L03762  (null)
```

So tried that

```
UPDATE (SELECT ho.HOOK_OFFICE_LETTER || LPAD(khc.HOOK_NO, 5, '0') AS hookey, eq.LOCATION_DESCRIPTION AS eqloc
        FROM KEY_HOOK_CURRENT khc 
            INNER JOIN KEY_HOLDING kho                ON khc.KEY_HOLDINGOID = kho.KEY_HOLDINGOID
            INNER JOIN CONTRACT con                   ON kho.CUSTOMEROID = con.CUSTOMEROID
            INNER JOIN VW_CURRENT_CONTRACT_PERIOD ccp ON con.CONTRACT_ID = ccp.CONTRACT_ID
            INNER JOIN CONTRACT_PERIOD cp             ON (ccp.CONTRACT_ID = cp.CONTRACT_ID AND ccp.CONTRACT_PERIOD = cp.CONTRACT_PERIOD)
            INNER JOIN CONTRACT_EQUIP_PERIOD cep      ON cp.CONTRACT_PERIODOID = cep.CONTRACT_PERIODOID
            INNER JOIN EQUIPMENT eq                   ON cep.EQUIPMENTOID = eq.EQUIPMENTOID
            INNER JOIN HOOK_OFFICE ho                 ON khc.HOOK_OFFICEOID = ho.HOOK_OFFICEOID
        WHERE
        eq.PRODUCT_ID = 'XXX' AND
        (eq.LOCATION_DESCRIPTION IS NULL OR (ho.HOOK_OFFICE_LETTER || LPAD(khc.HOOK_NO, 5, '0')) <> eq.LOCATION_DESCRIPTION))
SET hookno = eqloc

     but getting 01733 - "virtual column not allowed"
```

... and lots of other queries including merge but don't have much experience with that so no much luck! :(

Please Note: This query will run every 10min 24/7 so it should be pretty quick (if possible) and update only when necessary.

Your help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: A MERGE statement is the way to go, here, but you'll need some way of identifying which row(s) in the equipment table need to be updated. What is the primary key of the equipment table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the equipment table's primary key is equipmentoid, we can create the MERGE statement as follows:

```
merge into equipment tgt
using (select eq.equipmentoid,
              ho.hook_office_letter || lpad(khc.hook_no, 5, '0') as hookno,
              eq.location_description as eqloc
       from key_hook_current khc 
           inner join key_holding kho                on khc.key_holdingoid = kho.key_holdingoid
           inner join contract con                   on kho.customeroid = con.customeroid
           inner join vw_current_contract_period ccp on con.contract_id = ccp.contract_id
           inner join contract_period cp             on (ccp.contract_id = cp.contract_id and ccp.contract_period = cp.contract_period)
           inner join contract_equip_period cep      on cp.contract_periodoid = cep.contract_periodoid
           inner join equipment eq                   on cep.equipmentoid = eq.equipmentoid
           inner join hook_office ho                 on khc.hook_officeoid = ho.hook_officeoid
       where
           eq.product_id = 'XXX' and
           (eq.location_description is null or
            ho.hook_office_letter || lpad(khc.hook_no, 5, '0') <> eq.location_description)) src
  on (tgt.equipmentoid = src.equipmentoid)
when matched then
update set tgt.location_description = src.hookno;
```

All I've done is taken your select statement, added in a reference to the primary key column of your equipment table, which allows us to join the source subquery back to the table and update the relevant rows.

Comment: Thank you very much Boneist! Rushing to check it out straight away... It looks suspiciously easy ;-)

Comment: That's the beauty of the merge statement - if you have the sql statement generating the results that you're after, it's often just a case of plugging it into as the source part of the merge. (Of course, sometimes you can amend the source query to remove the target table, and force the join as part of the merge statement, which can make it run quicker, but I'm not sure that will make a difference in this case)

Comment: It WORKED!! :) PURE AWESOMENESS. Boneist I learnt more from your kind answer than from those dozens of oracle manual pages I looked up throughout today. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to be of help *{:-)

Answer (score 0):

Look like you want divide location_description to one letter and 5-digits numeric code and assign it to HOOK_OFFICE_LETTER and HOOK_NO.

```
UPDATE ho 
    INNER JOIN KEY_HOLDING kho                ON khc.KEY_HOLDINGOID = kho.KEY_HOLDINGOID
    INNER JOIN CONTRACT con                   ON kho.CUSTOMEROID = con.CUSTOMEROID
    INNER JOIN VW_CURRENT_CONTRACT_PERIOD ccp ON con.CONTRACT_ID = ccp.CONTRACT_ID
    INNER JOIN CONTRACT_PERIOD cp             ON (ccp.CONTRACT_ID = cp.CONTRACT_ID AND ccp.CONTRACT_PERIOD = cp.CONTRACT_PERIOD)
    INNER JOIN CONTRACT_EQUIP_PERIOD cep      ON cp.CONTRACT_PERIODOID = cep.CONTRACT_PERIODOID
    INNER JOIN EQUIPMENT eq                   ON cep.EQUIPMENTOID = eq.EQUIPMENTOID
    INNER JOIN HOOK_OFFICE ho                 ON khc.HOOK_OFFICEOID = ho.HOOK_OFFICEOID

SET HOOK_OFFICE_LETTER = SUBSTRING(eq.location_description,1,1),
--cut letter and assignto HOOK_OFFICE_LETTER 
khc.HOOK_NO =   SUBSTRING(eq.location_description,2,5) 
--cut 5-digit code and assign to khc.HOOK_NO
WHERE
    eq.PRODUCT_ID = 'XXX' AND
        (eq.LOCATION_DESCRIPTION IS NULL) OR
        ((ho.HOOK_OFFICE_LETTER || LPAD(khc.HOOK_NO, 5, '0') <> eq.LOCATION_DESCRIPTION))
```

But probably you want update eq.location_description to value of (ho.HOOK_OFFICE_LETTER || LPAD(khc.HOOK_NO, 5, '0')
of so, use next query:

```
 UPDATE ho 
        INNER JOIN KEY_HOLDING kho                ON khc.KEY_HOLDINGOID = kho.KEY_HOLDINGOID
        INNER JOIN CONTRACT con                   ON kho.CUSTOMEROID = con.CUSTOMEROID
        INNER JOIN VW_CURRENT_CONTRACT_PERIOD ccp ON con.CONTRACT_ID = ccp.CONTRACT_ID
        INNER JOIN CONTRACT_PERIOD cp             ON (ccp.CONTRACT_ID = cp.CONTRACT_ID AND ccp.CONTRACT_PERIOD = cp.CONTRACT_PERIOD)
        INNER JOIN CONTRACT_EQUIP_PERIOD cep      ON cp.CONTRACT_PERIODOID = cep.CONTRACT_PERIODOID
        INNER JOIN EQUIPMENT eq                   ON cep.EQUIPMENTOID = eq.EQUIPMENTOID
        INNER JOIN HOOK_OFFICE ho                 ON khc.HOOK_OFFICEOID = ho.HOOK_OFFICEOID

    SET eq.location_description = (ho.HOOK_OFFICE_LETTER || LPAD(khc.HOOK_NO, 5, '0')
    WHERE
        eq.PRODUCT_ID = 'XXX' AND
        (eq.LOCATION_DESCRIPTION IS NULL) OR
        ((ho.HOOK_OFFICE_LETTER || LPAD(khc.HOOK_NO, 5, '0') <> eq.LOCATION_DESCRIPTION))
```